# receiving "out of range" error, can't figure out why

Tags: vba, excel

Let me start by first thanking everyone for the help/intention to help.  This community is phenomenal.  Second:  I'm pretty new at this- before this week I'd learned basic in highschool a decade ago but no other programming experience outside of theory.

Without further ado, here's my issue:

Working on code to find unique variables (I know there's a lot of opensource stuff out there, need to customize this though).  When I go to populate the array with the very first string I run into an 'out of range' error at array(1), which I had explicity set (1 TO UB), with UB being the upper bound.  I've also double checked the value of UB with msgbox and it's at 15 with my dummy data, so that shouldn't be an issue.  I've set the values in the array to empty (have also done so with 0, to no avail).

The error occurs at "ResultArray(1) = CurrentArray(1)"

I'm at a loss; any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit


Sub unque_values()


'''''''''Variable declaration
'
'   CurrentArray() is the array taken from the worksheet
'   Comp is the method of comparing inputs (either case sensitive or case insensitive)
'   resultarray() is the array that unique values are placed
'   UB is the upper bound of Result Array
'   resultindex is the variable that keeps track of which cells are unique and which are not
'   n is a helped variable that assists with resizing the array

Dim currentarray() As Variant
Dim comp As VbCompareMethod
Dim resultarray() As Variant
Dim UB As Long
Dim resultindex As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim v As Variant
Dim inresults As Boolean
Dim m As Long


' set variables to default values
Let comp = vbTextCompare
Let n = 0

' count the number of cells included in currentarray and populate with values
Let n = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A").Count
Let UB = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & n).End(xlUp).Row



' dimension arrays
ReDim resultarray(1 To UB)
ReDim currentarray(1 To UB)
' don't forget to change to named ranges
Let currentarray() = Range("f2", "f" & UB)



' populate resultarray with empty values

For n = LBound(resultarray) To UBound(resultarray)
resultarray(n) = Empty
Next n



MsgBox (n)



'check for invalid values in array
For Each v In currentarray
    If IsNull(n) = True Then
        resultarray = CVErr(xlErrNull)

        Exit Sub
    End If
Next v


' assumes the first value is unique
resultindex = 1
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''error is this line''''''''''''''
resultarray(1) = currentarray(1)

' Search for duplicates by cycling through loops
' n = index of value being checked
' m = index of value being checked against
 For n = 2 To UB
    Let inresults = False
    For m = 1 To n
        If StrComp(CStr(resultarray(m)), CStr(currentarray(n)), comp) = 0 Then
            inresults = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next m

    If inresults = False Then
        resultindex = resultindex + 1
        resultarray(resultindex) = currentarray(n)
    End If
    Next n

ReDim Preserve resultarray(1 To resultindex)




End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A").Count` will always give you the same answer, which is the maximum number of rows (65536). This **could** be the problem.

Comment: I'm intentionally doing it like that so I can come from the bottom to ensure I find the true last cell as opposed to the next blank cell.  Thank you for the response!

Comment: See [this](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/) to find the last row. Otherwise, which line is raising the error?

Comment: haha, that probably should have been in the question itself.  the line with error is "Resultarray(1) = currentarray(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've assigned to `currentArray` a range array. These are always two-dimensional arrays.

[image]

You should be able to resolve it with:

```
resultarray(1) = currentarray(1, 1)
```

You would need to modify a few more lines in your code to refer to *both* dimensions of the array.

Alternatively, with the least manipulation to your existing code, transpose the array which turns it to a one-dimensional array. This should require no other changes to your code.

```
Let currentArray() = Application.Transpose(Range("f2", "f" & UB))
```

Comment: You, sir, are my hero.  I've spent about two hours on this sucker-- thank you so much.

Comment: Cheers. One of the best things you can do as a beginner is learn how to debug using the Locals window. Especially with arrays/etc. you can see their structure and examine their values, etc. If you haven't seen this yet, there are a bunch of great tips for debugging: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Try with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Columns(1).cells.Count`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  The issue I"m having though is with the 'out of range' error given that the range is resultarray(1 to UB)  and currentarray(1 to ub) where UB = 15, so when I set resultarray(1) = currentarray(1) I don't know why it's out of range.  also, UB = 15 has been confirmed by simply adding msgbox(UB) to the code, and it checks out.